# How to inject values from application.yaml to Junit 5 Test case

Tags: spring-boot, junit5

I am using Junit5 to write unit test cases in java. I have few values that I have added in application.yaml but I am not able to retrieve them in my test file eg. ownerMasterList value is coming as null but it is present in application.yaml

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class OwnerServiceTest {
@Value("${owner.master-list}") 
private ownerMasterList;

@Test 
void findAllOwners(){
  ---test detail
 }

}
```

Comment: your file is in  test\resources?

Comment: @VeKe Yes, file is in test\resources

Comment: Which version of spring boot?

Comment: Spring boot version - 2.3.4.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

> Using ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer alone does not provide support for @Value("${…​}") injection. Its only job is to ensure that application.properties files are loaded into Spring’s Environment. For @Value support, you need to either additionally configure a PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer or use @SpringBootTest, which auto-configures one for you.

From [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.2.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-configfileapplicationcontextinitializer-test-utility)

```
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
        public class OwnerServiceTest {...}
```

Please try providing property source

Comment: I found some information on docs, can you try accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

By reading your code, it seems that you are using JUnit5 (`@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)`).

The correct extension to use to trigger the launch of a Spring application context is (`@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)`). If you are using Spring Boot, you can use the `@SpringBootTest` annotation which is itself annotated with `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)`.

One point to note though: you should not wire an application context when unit testing your code. You should rather test your class in isolation and inject the needed property (here `ownerMasterList`) through the constructor (see `@BeforeEach` JUnit 5 annotation):

```java
class OwnerServiceTest {

    private OwnerService ownerService;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        this.ownerService = new OwnerService(new ArrayList<>(...));
    }
}
```